# "Slide" segue between UITabBar views

Tags: ios, ios5, uitabbarcontroller, uistoryboard

My iOS 5 app uses storyboarding with a `UITabBarController`. There are three "tabs" each displaying a view controller which has been linked using a relationship back to the `UITabBarController`. At the moment each view controller appears when you tap the relevant tab, as expected. However, for a more gracious transition I would like to slide the view controllers on and off screen.

By way of example, if I am currently on Tab 0 and then select Tab 1 the view controller on screen (for Tab 0) should slide off to the left-hand side of the screen, and the new view controller (for Tab 1) should slide on from the right-hand side of the screen.

I have been able to achieve this behaviour using a custom `UIView` as the tab bar but would like to know whether this is possible with a custom segue in storyboarding, as that would certainly save a lot of coding (and also would keep things a fair bit neater in the project)?

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 1):

I am trying to do the same thing.

Unfortunately I think the relationship segue does not allow any customization as it just connect tab bar and the tab bar items together, and not a transition.

My guess is we have to do the transition ourselves when the view appeared.